# Navigate to slide when clicking anchor jQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using jQuery cycle to scroll between div's on a single page site.

Each div inside the `slides` `div` has an `id` that I was hoping to use the hash for scrolling from a `nav`. The `nav` is sitting outside of the div that cycle is hooked into.

The markup looks like this;

```
<nav>    
    <ul>
            <li>Our challenges
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#explore">Government Current &amp; Emerging Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#industry">Industry Challenges</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bis">BIS Objectives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#activities">Activities</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</nav>


<div class="slides">
    //divs with id's for navigation
</div
```

If I click the industry anchor, nothing happens, so I wonder if there is anything from the cycle options that I can use to hook into my nav block?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I can use pagerAnchorBuilder to build the contents of my nav. I'm just not sure what to pass in to build the list.

Answer (score 0):

Using this http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager6.html for guidance and editing the pagerAnchorBuilder function to match my markup has given me what I need.